# Ignore top-level domain in web.config redirection

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

We have a number of domains (e.g., `domain1`, `domain2`) across a number of top-level domains (e.g., `tld1`, `tld2`) all of which, including their subdomains, currently redirect to `domain1.tld1` with the following rule:

```xml
<rule>
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain1\.tld1$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain1.tld1/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

However we would now like to retain the top-level domains when redirecting - that is: the redirection should be to `domain1.tld1` or `domain1.tld2`, depending on the original TLD entered. After some trial & error and searching I can't quite seem to figure it out, though. This was my latest attempt, which was redirecting to `domain1.` without a TLD:

```xml
<rule>
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain1\.(.*)$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain1.{C:1}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Ideally, we'd like a solution that wouldn't require us to add new top-level domains as more domains are acquired. So, if `domain1.tld3` and `domain2.tld3` are registered tomorrow, there shouldn't be a need to edit the web.config file to add `tld3`.

Answer (score 1):

Try capturing the TLD in its own condition like so:

```
<rule>
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain1\." negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^\[\w\d-]+\.(.[\w\d]+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain1.{C:1}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks, James; with a little modification, that's working *except* on subdomains of `domain1` - `www.domain1.tld1` will redirect to `domain1.domain1.tld1` instead of `domain1.tld`.

Comment: Could remove the caret (^) from the start of the first condition or replace that regex with something more robust.

Comment: Actually, changing the second pattern to `^\[\w\d\.-]+\.([\w\d]+)` would probably work but I haven't tested it. Changing that regex to recognise any valid hostname should work afaik.

Comment: I'm getting a little closer, have it working with all domains and TLDs now, bar `.co.uk`, using `^.*\.(.*)` for the second condition. Just need to build from that.

Comment: Got it! `^(www\.)?.*?\.(.*)$` for the second condition and replace `{C:1}` with `{C:2}`. Hardcoding the subdomains isn't ideal but it'll do the job for now. Thanks for the help, man.

Answer (score 0):

I got there in the end, thanks in part to [James' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48994353/4768433) to add another condition:

```xml
<rule>
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain1\." negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?.*?\.(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain1.{C:2}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Hardcoding the subdomain(s) isn't ideal for my situation, but it does the job.